# How to address the recipient if you are writing to a generic department address?

Tags: professionalism, email

Often I come across generic department e-mails - usually from HR departments - and I have difficulty in knowing who to address. E-mails such as *recruiting@abc.com* or *join@xyz.org* for example.

What would be a polite, but not over the top, manner to address the recipient? I've often started with *Dear Sir or Madam*, but I find it extremely formal.

In the same manner, how can I reply to an e-mail from a department if it has not been "signed" by a specific person in that department. For example:

*Dear John,*

E-MAIL CONTENT

*XYZ Recruiting Team.*

Thanks!

Comment: Emails never need salutations. Just skip it.

Comment: I feel that would be verging on impolite - especially in Europe/UK. I'm always addressed by name by business partners from Europe (even a "Hi..."), but often US partners usually don't even bother with that - which shows the cultural difference, I guess.

Comment: Agreed, I think that would be impolite in the UK.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about grammar.

Comment: @JimG - Seems to be more about etiquette.

Comment: @HLGEM I very rarely see an email **without** a salutation, with the exception of a reply to another email (well, assuming "Hi", or even just the person's name, counts as a salutation) (emails not addressed to anyone, perhaps sent to a few people, have a decent chance of getting lost to the void - some people get CC'ed on so many things that it would be near impossible for them to read everything in enough detail, or even know to reply).

Comment: I usually go with "To whom it may concern" in the covering letter (not great, but it's hard when you're not given a contact name) but simply "Hi there" in the email itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had success by addressing the email to the whole team.

> Hello *ABC Team*
>
> Would you be able to assist me with... REST OF CONTENT
>
> *Matt*

Replying to an email that came from a team is even easier, as you can reply back to the same entity that "signed" the original email, even if it was not a specific person.

For example:

> *Dear John,*
>
> E-MAIL CONTENT
>
> *XYZ Recruiting Team.*

Can be replied to as:

> *Dear XYZ Recruiting Team,*
>
> Thank you for reaching out to me...
>   REST OF RESPONSE
>
> *John*

This has worked for me in the US, I am not sure if expectations are different in Europe/UK.

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt about who to address, for instance if you're e-mailing a group e-mail which you've never had any correspondence with previously, then address no one. A simple *hi* is normally sufficient:

> Hi
>
> I'm enquiring about blah. Stuff and things.
>
> Kind regards
> Your Name

People are more than used to informality in e-mails and it looks weird if you attempt to do more. If you're worried about appearing overly informal then use the team's name:

> Hi Recruiting Team
>
> Stuff and things...

In the case of )join@example.com_ writing *Dear Join* would appear a little strange; if you're really wedded to the idea of talking to an entity you can address the company - the people sat behind the e-mail are representing the company after all:

> Hi Example Ltd
>
> Stuff and things...

In the latter two examples feel free to substitute *Hi* for *Dear*; using *Dear* in this situation sounds less strange to me, in UK, but I imagine it'd be overly formal elsewhere.

If you're received an e-mail from someone then respond to the person or entity that signed the e-mail - you're not going to be incorrect then.

#### tl;dr: If in doubt don't mention anyone.

Comment: That's true, you can't write "Dear Join"...Well pointed out